# SpringBoot FlywayCallback not present

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I try to set up old project and it works yestarday but today I faced with strange error when try to executed application

```
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
```

this is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.4"
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5434/spd_talks'
    user = 'admin'
    password = '111'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.spdu'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}

bootJar{
    archiveName = "spd_talks.jar"
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'

    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.4.0'
    
    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '3.0'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
    testCompile group: 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions', name: 'flyway-spring-test', version: '5.2.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.24.0'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.4'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.7.25'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

    testCompile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'

    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4"

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '3.3.0'

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.11.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring5', version: '3.0.11.RELEASE'
}
```

when I executed gradle build I did not faced with some error

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~/hosts/java/spring_chat_jdbc_sockjs$ gradle build --refresh-dependencies --no-build-cache -x test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

what happen and how to resolve it ?

Comment: What configuration for flyway do you have in your application.yml? Also the error occurs when?

Comment: I don't have application.yml, all conf variables about flyway located in build.gradle file, section flyway

Comment: Where is the error occurring? In gradle or when you run the application? If it is when you run the application, then you need an application.yml to configure (and activate) flyway.